# AngularJS :wait in 'link' of directive is not working

Tags: angularjs

In the below source, the watch method in the link part of a custom directive is not working. I use 'link' within the directive because I have to update the DOM structure.

How can I get the watch in the link{} of the directive working EACH time the button is pushed?

**EDIT**: I found the wrong code. See below 'ERROR' and 'CORRECT' code.

The HTML above this script is (click on a button to increment a variable):

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as vmx">
    <button ng-click="vmx.incrementFoo()">Increment Foo</button>:
    {{ vmx.fooCount }}.
    <div foo-count-updated></div>
</div>
```

Angular code:

```
angular.module( "myapp", [])
 .controller( "AppController", myAppController)
   .directive('showAlsoInCustomDirective', showAlsoInCustomDirective);

   // *** CONTROLLER
   function myAppController( $scope ) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.fooCount = 0;
    vm.copiedFooCount = 0; 

    // ERROR code: 
    // **vm.getFooCount** = function() { 
    //    return vm.fooCount;
    // }

    // CORRECT code: 
    getFooCount = function() { 
      return vm.fooCount;
    }
    vm.getFooCount = getFooCount; 

    vm.incrementFoo = incrementFoo;
    function incrementFoo() {
      ++vm.fooCount;
    }
  }

 // *** DIRECTIVE 
.directive('fooCountUpdated', fooCountUpdater);
function fooCountUpdater() {
    var indirectivecounter = 0; 
    getFooCountInDirective = function() { 
        return getFooCount();
    }
    var watcherFn = function (watchScope) {
        return getFooCountInDirective();
    }
    return { 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(watcherFn, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                element.html( "Got the change: " + newValue);
            })
        }};
    }
```

The complete source is put in this file: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/J6nfLQ3dmLW0gDNXV0J5?p=preview

Comment: *"How can I get his working"*... You haven't explained what higher level problem you are trying to solve. Why do you need to use `$eval()` inside the watch? What's wrong with `return vm.getFooCount()`?

Comment: The above version (getFooCount() { return vm.fooCount; } works here. In a large example, this getFooCount() is not triggered each time. So, the $Eval version is needed.

Comment: That explanation doesn't really make sense

Comment: Hmm. It takes a lot of time to extract the core issue from a large example. I will try. Why is it a problem: It is because the **link** method in a custom directive (so not the controller) is called only **ONCE** when the DOM is scanned. So it won't re-execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated above, the solution was simple. It is also in the plunker file.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as vmx">
    <button ng-click="vmx.incrementFoo()">Increment Foo</button>:
    {{ vmx.fooCount }}.
    <div foo-count-updated></div>
</div>
```

Angular code:

```
angular.module( "myapp", [])
.controller( "AppController", function( $scope ) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.fooCount = 0;
    getFooCount = function() { 
        return vm.fooCount;
    }
    vm.getFooCount = getFooCount;
    vm.incrementFoo = incrementFoo;
    function incrementFoo() {
        ++vm.fooCount;
    }
})
.directive('fooCountUpdated', fooCountUpdater);
function fooCountUpdater() {
    var indirectivecounter = 0; 
    getFooCountInDirective = function() { 
        return getFooCount();
    }
    var watcherFn = function (watchScope) {
        return getFooCountInDirective();
    }
    return { 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(watcherFn, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            element.html( "Got the change: " + newValue);
         })
    }};
 }
```